# reading characters using fgetc

Tags: c, fgetc

I have been trying to read a file using fgetc but i am unable
to break the line into the pieces that i require

ex if i have: x:   xx xxx, xxxx;
and i want to break that into:

x

xx

xxx

xxxx

Comment: You can use `strchr` to find delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

i would split the task into 2 parts. Read the line; break it apart. USe getline to read the line. There are several ways to break it up; strchr is probably yr best bet

Answer (score 0):

If you keep using the character parsing method, you will need to do more string management on buffer to keep track of what you want to print. I don't see any reseting of num_chars after each match, nor any addition to the buffer to terminate the string prior to printing [code]buffer[num_chars] = 0;